# Узнать количество символов в тексте и добавить класс элементу.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер. Возможно ли такое реализовать в Jquery?

Есть определенное количество элементов. Мне нужно узнать количество символов у каждого элемента. Если у элемента символов (букв) больше 28 то добавить класс.

```
$(".product span").each(function(i) {
   var number = $(this).text();
      if (number.length > 28) {
         $(".product_cat span").addClass("level");
      }
});
```

Я попробовал так, но что то не учел.

Comment: Покажите html код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что так:

```
$(".product span").each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).text().length > 28) {
         $(this).addClass("level");
      }
});
```

P.S. И класс будет добавляться к элементу <span>. Если нужно к ".product", то используйте parent() или closest()

---

**Стоп!** Я проморгал то, что у вас добавляется класс к какому-то другому элементу с родителем ".product_cat". Тогда нужно знать структуру и как связаны все эти элементы.

Comment: Спасибо получилось! Вместо "product_cat" должно быть "product" я забыл поменять простите. Все шикарно, сработало!

Comment: @Deonis я бы лучше filter использовал.